# Is there a word describing the derivatives of an object's motion?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, classical-mechanics

Consider an object moving along a straight line. One might say something about its displacement, velocity or acceleration. These are the 0th, 1st and 2nd derivatives of the object's displacement. However, there are an infinite number of derivatives although we may rarely talk about the 1001st derivative.

Is there a name for the infinite set: {0th derivative of displacement, 1st derivative of displacement, 2st derivative of displacement, ......... }?

I've come across the problem of trying to describe this set in writing a mathematical piece of work related to the Maclaurin/Taylor series.

So far, I describe it as "derivatives of the object's motion" although I'm not too sure if this is quite right.

Comment: Position, velocity and acceleration are names of physical quantities, originating from classical mechanics, esp. Newtonian second order differential equations for forces. In mathematics one just calls the derivatives derivatives.

Comment: If that is the case, then would: "an object's derivatives" be generally understood?

Comment: An object has no derivatives. The object's position has.

Comment: Yes - and I'm looking for the particular word which describes those ones (if there is such a word).

Comment: Just $n$-th order derivatives or derivatives IMHO.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41243/392

Comment: also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/143826/3301

Answer (score 1):

Here is a common convention for position derivatives

- 0<sup>th</sup> Derivative : Position
- 1<sup>st</sup> Derivative : Speed
- 2<sup>nd</sup> Derivative : Acceleration
- 3<sup>rd</sup> Derivative : Jerk <sup>`[1]`</sup>
- 4<sup>th</sup> Derivative : Snap/Jounce  <sup>`[2]`</sup>
- 5<sup>th</sup> Derivative : Crackle
- 6<sup>th</sup> Derivative : Pop
- 7<sup>th</sup> Derivative : Lock <sup>`[3]`</sup>
- 8<sup>th</sup> Derivative : Drop
- 9th Derivative : ???

Beyond that, it is just an academic exercise in naming as it way beyond any practical use.

**Footnotes**

1. [Names of higher-order derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143826/names-of-higher-order-derivatives)
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce
3. https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_physical_names_for_third_fourth_and_higher_order_derivatives_of_position

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I was looking for the general term to describe these derivatives, not the specific ones.

Comment: I think I have heard the collection of vectors $\vec{r}', \vec{r}'', \cdots$ referred to as the "osculating frame" or "osculating flag", assuming they are all linearly independent.